# Visual Studio extension to notify about TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

Is there an extension to show something (text, icon, whatever) when current project under TFS receives an update?

My problem: I am constantly forgetting to do "Get latest version". Seeing something should help.

P.S.: sorry if it's an offtopic, but I recall question regarding programming environment were allowed here and I am not asking for a library... unable to check for sure due to missing `Help` in the new shiny top bar.

Comment: Questions about the use of dev tools are on topic, but not recommendations for them. Suggestion: add an alert to TFS for any checkin to the team project,

Comment: @Richard, we are not doing checkins. What is alert? Newbie here. Edit: I think I don't have rights, I am a simple user, therefore question about extension to VS.

Comment: Alters are a way to get TFS to notify yourself (or a team) when something changes. Can include work items, builds as well as checkins. If you are not using checkins to modify the source held in TFS there will never be anything new when doing "get latest version". (TFS has checkins, git has commits, ...)

Comment: If alerts are done by email, then it's not what I want. It sounds uncomfortable. And as for checkins, me or my collegues are not checking in anything specifically, but we may work on a same project or branch and I'd really like to get notified inside Visual Studio itself. I can imagine what extension can periodically poll for changeset and somehow check if current project files are affected.

Comment: Firstly: all changes to source code in TFS are done via checkins, if there are no checkins there will be no changes. Secondly: someone may have an extension but *tool recommendations are off topic*.

Comment: @Sinatr What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

No such extension by default. The easiest way would be creating [an alert](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) as @Richard mentioned. When there is a check-in under a team project or a specific path, you would need to perform Get Latest, so you can create a Checkin alert.

[image]

Alternatively you could add a script to your source control. In this script, you can use [tf get](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) command to do get latest. You can always run this script when you would like to run.